# Understanding what an HTTP endpoint is

Tags: http

I'm reading through the ASP.NET docs and found this: "Every public method in a controller is callable as an HTTP endpoint." But, what is an HTTP endpoint? Please help me understand, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP endpoint is a targetable URL in the web application, such as https://localhost:5001/HelloWorld, and combines the protocol used: HTTPS, the network location of the web server (including the TCP port): localhost:5001 and the target URI HelloWorld.

Answer (score 0):

How and what is an HTTP endpoint:

1. HTTP endpoint is the entry way for API, so for example e.g., "https://coffeebrews.com/api/brews"
2. Endpoint == Point of Connection

How HTTP endpoint works in ASP.NET MVC apps:

1. A user sends a request to the **server** through URL
2. The **server** receives the request and matches it with the appropriate Controller Action
3. Controller Action processes the request and sends a response back to the user